# Which diagram use for drawing the detail of the web site process

Tags: diagram

After drawing an activity diagram of my shopping web site, I want to draw the details about each action of process in my site such as :

```
 - Register User : insert a record to User table.
 - Exchange gift card : insert a log to Log table
 - blah blah .....
```

Then how can I draw the diagram that can describe these action.

Comment: What are you really asking here ?  I could offer the answer *Take a pencil and a sheet of paper, hold the pencil with the pointed end towards the paper, ...* but I sense that that is not the sort of answer you want.  Can you explain more of your problem and question ?

Comment: oh sorry my bad, I want to know, is there any program to draw it?

Comment: You could try MS Visio, OmniGraffle, that sort of thing.  But SO isn't a good substitute for a search engine, nor does it aspire to be.